# Why does jfilechooser open to Documents?

Tags: java

in Windows 7, why does jfilechooser open to Documents??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [JFileChooser documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html):

> This default depends on the operating system. **It is typically the "My Documents" folder on Windows**, and the user's home directory on Unix.

If you're asking "why did Sun default to that directory?": Microsoft recommends, in their user interface guidelines, defaulting to that directory - it's where they'd expect users to save the bulk of their personal files. You can override that choice, by using a [different constructor overload](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#JFileChooser(java.io.File)):

```
public JFileChooser(File currentDirectory)
```

> Constructs a JFileChooser using the given File as the path.

Comment: i guess i wasn't that specific.  When I ask why it is because I am trying understand  where the command is that points it to "Documents" folder and how it works and where I can change the folder it opens up to.

Comment: @doug: see my edit. Also, bookmark the docs for future reference. Everything you need is there. http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/

Comment: @doug: not sure what you mean by "where the command is that points it to "Documents" folder and how it works". Hope my answer helps.